# Google Earth shows a black screen and options are greyed out

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, google-earth

I have installed the latest .deb Google Earth from Google, but the Google window is black (where the earth should be) Plus all 3D options are greyed out.

I have checked my graphics card, and 3D is enabled.

As shown here:

```
pst007x@pst007x-ubuntu64:~$  /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p  
OpenGL vendor string:   Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile 
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 7.11

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
pst007x@pst007x-ubuntu64:~$
```

I have never been able to get Google earth to work on Radeon, Nvidia and Intel cards.

I have followed installation instructions, but no luck.

What is odd that in the options menu, the 3D settings page is all greyed out, I am unable to select any option.

I have looked at other threads and no answers.

I have set my DNS to manual, ipv6 is off....

I am at a loss on this one...

UPDATE:

I now get the error: We are unable to connect to the Google Earth servers

However I do not use a Proxy. I tried opening all ports in my routers firewall.

Still only a black window.

Now using Ubuntu 11.10 64bit..

Comment: if you run googleearth from a terminal what errors (if any) are reported (copy and paste into your question).

Comment: I have same problem. But only in Unity and Gnome (3 and Classic). I used Software Center and installed Xfce desktop, because Unity was too slow even if I disable all effects. It was just to slow for me. In login screen I choose between Gnome,Unity and Xfce.
I was really surprised when I saw that in xfce mode, Google Earth works just fine.But in Unity, and Gnome it does not.Maybe this fact will help someone to figure it out, what's the problem.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. I think its not about the DNS problem although I am in China because I am using premium vpn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. ISP DNS is rubbish! Changed my DNS and worked! OPENDNS nameservers are always: 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220, SITE LINK:https://store.opendns.com/start/

Answer (score 1):

Which (or any) of these methods have you tried?

**Method A:** (download binaries)

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install lsb-core
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs    (needed for Ubuntu 11.10, 64bit)

sudo apt-get install google-earth-stable
```

**Method B:** (download & compile)

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential lsb-core
sudo apt-get install googleearth-package

sudo make-googleearth-package --force
```

Comment: Thank you for that clear response. Now what version of Google Earth did you try to install?

Comment: It is intermittent. It worked for a few days then back to the black screen, I get a server failure now. Tried port forwarding, connected hard wired to a LAN, but haven't been able to get it back. I checked permissions, all correct. It must be a google earth issue, or I am extremely unlucky, because no matter what hardware I used I could never get it working. I did get the best results with the suggestion here though.  Thanks

Comment: Due to intermittent failure, I tried installing BETA version: Google Earth: 6.1.0.4857 (beta), Build Date: 10/2/2011, Build Time: 4:00:42 am,Renderer: OpenGL, Operating System: Linux  (3.0.0.0), Video Driver: Tungsten Graphics, Inc, Max Texture Size: 8192x8192
available video memory information not available, Server: kh.google.com

Comment: Found the problem. ISP DNS is rubbish! Changed my DNS and worked! OPENDNS nameservers are always: 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220, SITE LINK:https://store.opendns.com/start/

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install 3D drivers if you have an Nvidia or Radeon card.

Comment: My laptop uses Intel, and I have checked 3D is enabled. I also have a PC desktop using Nvidia card, using the latest drivers on Ubuntu 10.10 and I am still having the same issue. It is though Google Earth program will not see that my graphics 3D is enabled. I wonder if there is a config file I can change to force Google Earth to not check for 3D perhaps. thanks

Comment: I don't mean to offend anybody nor sound like a geek. The fact is that I have had same experience before and later found out it was due to censorship! Just check with your ISP provider for information, if their firewall is responsible for that or some other network related activities.

Answer (score 0):

you can also check if all the required libraries are properly linked to the executable with `ldd /opt/google/earth/free/googleearth-bin` , in particular look for the links with the GL related libraries.

Comment: tried that and the only odd thing is: libgoogleearth_free.so => not found

Answer (score 0):

Which country are you at? I have found out that it behaves that way with the error(We are unable to connect to the Google Earth servers) popping up each time it tries to connect due to some country censorship of 'Google Earth'.

Comment: I am in the UK, no censorship here... I hope :-(

Answer (score 0):

In router:
Internet IP Address

```
Get Dynamically from ISP: yes
```

Domain Name Server (DNS) Address

```
Get Automatically from ISP: yes
```